# Depth map normalization

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, depth, cifilter

I am applying `CIDepthBlurEffect` filter to a PHAsset as follows:

```
    PHImageManager.default().requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: self.asset!, options: imageOptions) { (data, responseString, imageOrientation, info) in
    
    if data != nil {
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if let depthImage  = CIImage(data: data!, options: [CIImageOption.auxiliaryDisparity : true])?.oriented(imageOrientation) {
                            
          if let newMainImage = CIImage(data: data!)?.oriented(imageOrientation) {
                                let filter = CIFilter(name : "CIDepthBlurEffect",
                                                      parameters: [kCIInputImageKey         : newMainImage,
                                                                   kCIInputDisparityImageKey: depthImage,
                                                                   "inputAperture"          : withRadius])
                                
                                self.imageView.image = UIImage(ciImage: filter!.outputImage!)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works great most of the time. However, sometimes, the filter blur planes seem to be off. Almost as the Z plane is wrong or shifted.

**Does this method require the depth data to be normalized?**

Previously, when `CVPixelBuffer` was used, I was using this extension:

```
final func normalize() -> CVPixelBuffer {
        
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(self)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(self)
        
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let floatBuffer = unsafeBitCast(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(self), to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.self)
        
        var minPixel: Float = 1.0
        var maxPixel: Float = 0.0
        
        for y in 0 ..< height {
            for x in 0 ..< width {
                let pixel = floatBuffer[y * width + x]
                minPixel = min(pixel, minPixel)
                maxPixel = max(pixel, maxPixel)
            }
        }
        
        let range = maxPixel - minPixel
        
        for y in 0 ..< height {
            for x in 0 ..< width {
                let pixel = floatBuffer[y * width + x]
                floatBuffer[y * width + x] = (pixel - minPixel) / range
            }
        }
        
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        return self
    }
```

Is there such a way to do this to a `CIImage`?

Comment: Hmm, since the filter expects the disparity data directly, I would assume you don't need to manually normalize it. Have you tried initializing the filter from the image data directly via this method of `CIContext`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cicontext/3020629-depthblureffectfilter

Comment: After using that method, Blur looks way weak for a given radius. Also, the image orientation seems off on landscape images, even after specifying the image orientation property. I basically followed this: https://www.coder.work/article/4391580